Try-runtime fails because of the onchain version of DmpQueue
has anybody encountered this issue? I discovered that when running the try-runtime, my DmpQueue is 0, which induces the try-runtime failure. However, I cannot find any migration code on DmpQueue. Does anyone know how to fix that?
[2024-09-14T20:35:33Z ERROR runtime::frame-support] DmpQueue: On chain storage version StorageVersion(0) doesn't match current storage version StorageVersion(2).                                                                                                 

Note: the DmpQueue is cumulus-pallet-dmp-queue.
DmpQueue: cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},


git blame shows this commit. Actual bump to version 2, seems to have happened here. Bump to version 1, here. Version 1 was introduced 2022 ... is your runtime really that old? Or is something else off?

If there was an DmpQueue::Completed event emitted, then the pallet can be removed from the runtime since the lazy migration completed.
Otherwise if your pallet was not at V2 prior to this, and did not run the lazy migration yet, the runtime needs to be updated to the version where the pallet has V2 first.

Thank you very much! I found the DmpQueue::Completed in our chain. I'll remove it from the runtime

The pallet was deprecated in this pull request. Sadly this pr has done some things in a not so good way among other things it deleted the migrations.
So, depending on your chain there are two things you can do:

If you don't have any open XCM channels, you can just remove the pallet at all.

If you have open XCM channels, you need to copy the old migration code that was removed in the pr above into your runtime. You will need to change it a little bit to make it compile, but then the error should be gone.


